# React losing state when component re-renders

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building an application that has a quizz section.
It's only meant to display one question at a time, and they're coming from an API as an array of questions.
I'd like to have a mechanism on the main Quizz component that would know which question is currently being displayed and, when there's a correct answer, move on to the next question.
It works fine for the first question, but once I arrive at the second question, React re-renders my component and my state is reset.

```
function Quizz() {
  const [selectedQuestion, setSelectedQuestion] = useState(0);

  const handleQuestionAnswer = useCallback((isRejection) => {
    setSelectedQuestion(selectedQuestion + 1);
  }, [setSelectedQuestion]);

  return {QuizzData.questions.map((question, i) => {
        if (i === selectedQuestion) {
          return (
            <Question data={question} clickCallback={handleQuestionAnswer} key={i} />
          );
        }
}
```

The Question component passes the callback to a child, which then invokes the function.

Comment: What state is "lost"? What are the steps to reproduce the issue? Do we need to see more of the app code as part of your [mcve]? Side note: it seems your `handleQuestionAnswer` callback is closing over the initial `selectedQuestion` state value of `0` and will only ever update to `1`. Is this the state that is "lost"?

Comment: Can you provide a runnable [mcve] so we can observe the problem?

Comment: That is precisely the issue, state only updating to `1` @DrewReese

Comment: Thats because you have missing item in your `[depsArray]` for `handleQuestionAnswer`. Which is `selectedQuestion`. Either add it, either  change to `setSelectedQuestion(prev => prev + 1)`.

Comment: That's precisely it, @SergeySosunov. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`handleQuestionAnswer` is closing over the initial state value. Use a functional state update to correctly update from previous state instead of whatever is closed over in callback scope.

Example:

```
const handleQuestionAnswer = useCallback((isRejection) => {
  setSelectedQuestion(selectedQuestion => selectedQuestion + 1);
}, [setSelectedQuestion]);
```

See [Functional Updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) for more details.

General "Rule of Thumb": If the *next* React state value depends on the *previous* state value, i.e. incrementing a count, use a functional state update.

Comment: Is `setSelectedQuestion` needed in depsArray?

Comment: @SergeySosunov No, not really since the state updater function is guaranteed to be a stable reference, but the linter may complain about it missing since all it sees is a function declared each render cycle. You could certainly omit it as a dependency and add a `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` comment a line above the dependency array to ignore it or indicate "Go away linter, I know what I'm doing!"

Answer (score 0):

Your handleQuestionAnswer useCallback seems to have the wrong dependencies, you probably meant `selectedQuestion` instead of `setSelectedQuestion`.

As you used the wrong dependencies, your handleQuestionAnswer does not 'update'  and is only binded to selectedQuestion=0 (as setSelectedQuestion never update)

configured eslint might have help you notice this issue, so it is worth taking time to set it up !